# Background Animation not working in JQuery 1.4.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I was following a tutorial online for animating a background image to give a drop down effect.  I was supposed to download a plugin but it seems that that plugin is not available anymore.  Is there any other way to make the background animate?  I've looked through similar answers but none of them have worked.

Here's the code on jsfiddle: [Fiddle-Code](http://jsfiddle.net/mismael/6Vv9t/)

I want the drape.png image in the background to drop down like a curtain.  Also what is the latest version of jquery?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of jQuery is [1.7.1](http://jquery.com/)

This sort of animation is presentational. Consider doing it with [CSS3 animations and transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/). You will lose some browser support for the specific effect, but it will not interfere with functionality and will be easier to update and maintain.

Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/8SdA5/) I made for you. Is this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: Would you happen to know which browsers would support this type of animation of I used CSS3?

Comment: [Almost universal support](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition) for modern browsers besides Internet Explorer. Again, this is not essential functionality and accepting a little [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement) will help keep you sane. :-)